# OS X URL handler, but when launching the application?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've set a URL handler "soon" when my app is launching:
in -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*) :

```
[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(getUrl:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme((CFStringRef)@"myScheme", (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
```

It works as expected, the getUrl:withReplyEvent: is called whenever an URL with myScheme:// scheme is opened!

But if my app is **not running** (quit), if in Safari I open an URL such as myScheme://some_valuable_info?action=doSomething, it launched my app... but how do i know I've been *launched* by a URL handler? How can I get the URL that trigger my application launch?

Comment: It should call getUrl:withReplyEvent:, isn't it? Or otherwise I do not understand a question.

Comment: Yes it should, but it didn't. See my answer below: I was not registering the eventHandler soon enough!

Answer (score 6):

Responding to myself:

The eventHandler *must* be registered in the applicationWillFinishLaunching: , not in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

If the app is launched due to an URL handler, you'll still get the evenHandler callback, but only if you registered it very soon in the launching process.

Comment: I was doing that and it worked perfectly fine, but it appears to be broken in Ventura... am I the only one seeing this?